# GWT - how to prevent user from accessing other parts of application when popup is showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

I am rendering a html page that contains a button. 
I have bind a method to browser window that opens a gwt popup when the button is invoked.

My problem is, when i scroll the page, the popup stays fixed and the page scrolls. I want the popup to be scrolled along with the html page.

Also, the user should not be allowed to access other parts of app when the popup is open.

Can somebody help me

Comment: What is your question? What the title says, prevent accessing other parts or let the popup scroll with the page?

Comment: i want both to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the `PopupPanel` class, it is as easy as calling the right constructor:

[`PopupPanel(boolean autoHide, boolean modal)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#PopupPanel%28boolean,%20boolean%29)

> autoHide - true if the popup should be automatically hidden when the user clicks outside of it or the history token changes.
>
> modal - true if keyboard or mouse events that do not target the PopupPanel or its children should be ignored

So if you set the modal parameter, you cannot click outside of the popup, and also the scroll event should not happen at all (that is somewhat right, as scrolling a popup with a fixed positioning doesn't make much sense... Oh well, for a non advertising purpose at least).

Comment: This works only if the whole code is written in gwt. I am using plain html page that calls a gwt widget through window object